# Show value form choices field (formtype) in list view twig (Symfony2)

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I have a issue with choices and formtype. Short description of my problem :

I have formtype with field that has choices

```
->add('fieldName2', 'choice', array(
        'label' => 'Some label',
        'choices' => array(
            0 => 'Option 1',
            1 => 'Option 2',
            ...,
            n => 'Option n'
        ),
    ))
```

In database that field is int (must be a number). Now comes the problem : I want to list all the records for that table. Result is like :

```
fieldName1|fieldName2
----------|----------
somevalue | 0
somevalue | 1
somevalue | 2
```

but I wont to look like this:

```
fieldName1|fieldName2
----------|----------
somevalue | Option 1
somevalue | Option 2
somevalue | Option 3
```

How to combine formtype field choices and actual values in template. Do I have to create custom twig function for that or there is a built in solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `$data` contains your fields from a database in a controller, create the "choices" array:

```
$choices = array();
foreach ($data as $elem)
{
  $choices[$elem] = "Option {$elem}";
}
```

Then, create your form and pass your choices array in constructor.

```
$form = $this->createForm(new YourFormType($choices), new YourFormData());
```

In your form, add a constructor:

```
private $choices;

// (...)

public function __construct(array $choices)
{
  $this->choices = $choices;
}
```

Finally, create your field with your previously prepared array of choices.

```
(...)
->add('fieldName2', 'choice', array(
        'label' => 'Some label',
        'choices' => $this->choices,
))
```

Note: replace the property name "choices" by a less confusing name; will be easier to read if you have several choices that looks like this.

Comment: Hi Alain. You suggest that I should put choices array in controller and pass it to template and then there do something like this : {{ choices[entity.fieldName2] }} ?

Comment: Choices are now in formtype class.

Comment: No, do not pass it to the template, but to your form type's object.

Comment: I need to show value from database table. Form is working fine but in template view for showing all the records I need value to bi from choices array, not number. :)

Comment: I got your point yes. But when you declare your selectbox, you specify the `'choices'` attribute. This attribute takes an array, each key of this array will be each `<option>` values, where each value of this array will be what's displayed to the user. So, your `<select>` will look like `<select><option value="x">test</option></select>` if you declare `'choices' => array('x' => 'test')`. And you'll see "test" displayed.

Comment: I dont wont select :) , this isnt edit or new page. I wont to show all values from that table. I just need to see value of that column as if it was selected from that array :) My problem is that choices array is in the formtype object.

Comment: Oh, then, you can use `$data = $form->getData();` to get your entity (or an array if you do not use entity classes).

Comment: Hi Alain, there is no form data. Only choices array for listing all the records. Your answer was helpful so I will mark it as accepted :). Solution is to have choices data in controller, so its easy to pass that to formtype or template depending of what you trying to do (adding new record from form or listings records).